# How can I replay data in VanillaChronicle starting from a particular day?

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

Since VanillaChronicle stores data in different dirs named by dates, can I replay the data starting from a particular day? Sample codes are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can start at any index you wish. If you have a daily cycle, you can pick the index like this

```
long daysSince1970 = .... // days sicne 1/1/1970
long index = daysSince1970 << 40; // the default indecies per day
if (!tailer.index(index))
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not find this day");
// use the tailer from this point.
```